# Can't convert String to data class objects - Firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, data-class

I have read other comments on this same issue, but none of them has touched on a situation like mine

In mine, below describes how the data is structured:

```
{
   "symbols":{
      "alphabets":{
         "a":{
            "available":true,
            "text":"A",
            "timestamp":1.512686825309134E9
         },
         "b":{
            "available":true,
            "text":"B",
            "timestamp":1.512687248764272E9
         }"NameOfSymbols":"alphabets"
      }
   }
}
```

*The reason why mine is showing the error is that it can't convert the string `"NameOfSymbols" : "alphabets"` to the objects as specified in the data class

**So, what can be done about it, I use Kotlin**

*Is there a way I can exclude that part of the children value while I only get the one that is specified in the data class?*

**Data Class**

```
data class alphabets(
    val name: Names,
var NameOfSymbols: String? = null) {
    data class Names(

        var available: Boolean? = null,
        var text: String? = null,
        var timestamp: Long? = null) {

    }
}
```

Comment: How can you expect us to help you in your code without your code? Share the data class you've created.

Comment: And yes, you can very well exclude the fields you don't want by not declaring them in the data class.

Comment: I didn't declare the string, I declared the object only

Comment: i've added the data class

Comment: I tried to format your JSON, but `NameOfSymbols":"alphabets` seems not to be a part of it. Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file direcly from the Console?. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1):

This structure might work for your case (untested):

```
data class Message(
    @PropertyName("symbols") val symbols: Symbols,
)

data class Symbols(
    @PropertyName("alphabets") val alphabets: Alphabets,
)

data class Alphabets(
    @PropertyName("a") val a: Alphabet,
    @PropertyName("b") val b: Alphabet,
    @PropertyName("NameOfSymbols") val nameOfSymbols: String,
)

data class Alphabet(
    @PropertyName("available") val available: Boolean,
    @PropertyName("text") val text: String,
    @PropertyName("timestamp") val timestamp: Long,
)
```

Usage would be:

```
// in your ValueEventListener
override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    val value = snapshot.getValue<Message>()
}
```

If you want to exclude your `NameOfSymbols`, you should remove it, and add the `@IgnoreExtraProperties`, like shown below:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class Alphabets(
    @PropertyName("a") val a: Alphabet,
    @PropertyName("b") val b: Alphabet,
)
```

NOTE, I used these versions of firebase database:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:19.7.0'
```

Comment: Wow, this might work, I'll check it when I put on my computer

Comment: please, how can I relate this with my data class? (I've added my data class above) they look quite different, and most of the value used to read the data from the database is props passed from the previous screen, so is there a way I can bring in these variables into the property name argument

Answer (score 0):

ok, After reading the documentation on **Structuring Database** on the firebase docs website, [Structure your database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data?authuser=3#avoid_nesting_data)

**I realised that i didn't structure my database well, i should have regrouped them after specifying the name**
like below

```
{
  // This is a poorly nested data architecture, because iterating the children
  // of the "chats" node to get a list of conversation titles requires
  // potentially downloading hundreds of megabytes of messages
  "chats": {
    "one": {
      "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "messages": {
        "m1": { "sender": "ghopper", "message": "Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth." },
        "m2": { ... },
        // a very long list of messages
      }
    },
    "two": { ... }
  }
}
```

*Although, it said that structuring it that way isn't a nice way, it seems that's what works for me*