# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type Data class object KOTLIN

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, data-class

I have read other comments on this same issue, but none of them has touched on a situation like mine

In mine, below describes how the data is structured

```
      val ref: DatabaseReference? = Firebase.database.getReference("symbols/${alphabets}")
```

```
{
"symbols" : {
   "alphabets" : {
   "a" : {
       "available" : true,
       "text" : "A",
       "timestamp" : 1.512686825309134E9
   },
   "b" : {
       "available" : true,
       "text" : "B",
       "timestamp" : 1.512687248764272E9
   }

"NameOfSymbols" : "group of alphabets"
   }
}
}
```

> the list of the data continues, then the string is at the end of the objects

*The reason why mine is showing the error is because it can't convert the string "NameOfSymbols" : "alphabets" to the objects as specified in the data class

*So, what can be done about it, I use kotlin*

*Is there a way I can exclude that part of the children value while I only get the one that is specified in the data class?*

**Data Class**

```
data class alphabets(
    val name: Names,
var NameOfSymbols: String? = null) {
    data class Names(

        var available: Boolean? = null,
        var text: String? = null,
        var timestamp: Long? = null) {

    }
}
```

Comment: That JSON is invalid, please format it so we can help you (try to format it but can't guess the whole thing)

Comment: i've added the firebase reference

Comment: i'm using a recyclerview to view the list of the alphabets based on the ```text```

Comment: but, it can't make a data class of the string ```NameOfSymbols" : "group of alphabets```

Comment: so, my question is how can I exclude the string, or is there a different workaround? i have tried what was answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67272373/13617469, but it didnt work

Comment: Logging the snapshot to the console, works fine

Comment: Why is `alphabets` a variable?

Comment: It will be coming from a radio input, users will choose if they want to see alphabets, numbers or signs

Comment: What? Where are numbers, then? Where is the sign, then? Can you do the first thing I ask; that is not a valid JSON

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I exclude the string"?

Comment: The string there is a description of what type of data is stored there, bit I don't want it to interfere with the objects from the data class

Answer (score 0):

If you are listening to

```
"symbols/alphabets"
```

Then the children inside are:

```
"a" : {
   "available" : true,
   "text" : "A",
   "timestamp" : 1.512686825309134E9
}
```

That is a `Map<String, Any>` in this case we can define that `Any` into a specific `data class` as you want

```
data class Names(
    val available: Boolean? = null,
    val text: String? = null,
    val timestamp: Long? = null
)
```

Then you have that you have to transform your snapshot to:

```
Map<String, Names>
```

Comment: @RaphaelInyang you duplicate your own question and then reply it your self with a solution that was not the question asked, wow!